# How to create webhook from Google Apps Script using the "exec" url rather than "dev" url. Exec returns 403 Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks, trello

Been attempting to set-up a webhook in Google Sheets Apps Script that will respond when changes are made in Trello. To do this, it's suggested to deploy the script as a web app (requiring `doGet` and `doPost` functions that return HTML) to create a URL destination for receiving `post` and `get` requests.

The web app makes two URLs, one ends in `/dev` and is for development purposes (doesn't respond to `post` requests) and the other ends in `/exec` for normal access.

I've deployed the web app, both URL's are accessible and responsive in my browser (can view exec in incognito without sign-in), app is published to execute as "me" and be accessible by "anyone, even anonymous."

I have been able to successfully use the below code to create web-hooks for the `/dev` URL but not the `/exec` URL.

```
function create() {
  var url = 'https://api.trello.com/1/tokens/ae6ebe60b45abcd2d4aa945c9ab4c4571bd6b6f7856b1df0cd387fbffc649579/webhooks/?key=a211f4aca7fb3e521d652730dd231cb6'

  var payload = { 
    "key": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "token" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "callbackURL": "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw51TYGWHe95hKdcAs4l7E2eg0AtBi8e48lf_iafKYI/dev",
    "idModel":"xxxxxxxx",
    "description": "GW Test"  
  }
  var options = {"method" : "post",
                 "payload" : payload,
                 "muteHttpExceptions": true
                 };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
}
```

When using the `/dev` URL, I can see that a new web-hook is added in my Trello, but the `/exec` URL returns the following error:

{"message":"URL (https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxo90ucgXXz7MG6Z3wb2KD-PJn3akGKoelXLJ2mkg/exec) did not return 200 status code, got 403","error":"ERROR"}

So Trello was expecting a "200 Status Code" returned to verify that the script ran properly, but received 403 instead. What confuses me is why this doesn't happen when using `/dev`? How can I get it to accept my `/exec` URL?

More Info:

I can get my code to respond to `put`  and `get` requests when I use [link](https://apitester.com) or load the URL directly in my browser. It responds by filling the first six (6) cells in the spreadsheet.

I have republished as a new version and verified that the code still works, but I still get the error message from Trello saying that they received a 403 rather than 200 code. And I only receive this error when using `/exec` not `/dev`. And since `/dev` can't receive `post` requests, it isn't going to be helpful :(

Below is the remainder of an example:

```
function doSomething() {
  var values = [11,12];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:B1").setValue(values);
}


function create() {
  var url = 'https://api.trello.com/1/tokens/ae6ebe60b45abcd2d4aa945c9ab4c4571bd6b6f7856b1df0cd387fbffc649579/webhooks/?key=a211f4aca7fb3e521d652730dd231cb6'  
  var payload = { 
    "key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "token" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx": "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw51TYGWHe95hKdcAs4l7E2eg0AtBi8e48lf_iafKYI/dev",
    "idModel":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "description": "GW Test"  
  }
  var options = {"method" : "delete",
                 "payload" : payload,
              // "muteHttpExceptions": true
                 };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);           // creates webhook
}


// function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  doSomething();
  var values = [21,22];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:B2").setValue(values);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("something Get-ed");
}

function doPost(e) {
  doSomething();
  var values = [31,32];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A3:B3").setValue(values);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("something Posted");
  //var params = JSON.stringify(e);
}
```

Comment: In your situation, the endpoint of `/dev` works. But the endpoint of `/exec` doesn't work. From such situation, I thought that the latest script might not be reflected to Web Apps. So how about redeploying Web Apps as new version? By this, please test it again. If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize. If this didn't work, can you provide a script of Web Apps?

Comment: I can get my code to respond to `put`  and `get` requests when I use [link](https://apitester.com) or load the URL directly in my browser. It responds by filling the first six (6) cells in the spreadsheet. 

I have republished as a new version and verified that the code still works, but I still get the error message from Trello saying that they received a 403 rather than 200 code. And I only receive this error when using `/exec` not `/dev`. And since `/dev` can't receive `post` requests, it isn't going to be helpful :(

Comment: Can you try it in a new script file? It might be a concurrent issue. Publish a new script to call trello api from the new script in a new project to call the old published url? i.e., make a calling  project and published  project different. Also, try JSON stringifying payload..

Comment: I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: @Chuck's Keg Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 9):

How about this answer?

### Issue:

From your question, the following error is returned from API.

> {"message":"URL (https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxo90ucgXXz7MG6Z3wb2KD-PJn3akGKoelXLJ2mkg/exec) did not return 200 status code, got 403","error":"ERROR"}

About the reason of above error, at first, I thought that the latest script might not be reflected to Web Apps. But from your reply comment, it was found that the latest script was reflected to Web Apps. From this situation, I experimented for retrieving the error of `403` from the deployed Web Apps.

### Preparation:

As the preparation, Web Apps was deployed with "Execute the app as" and "Who has access to the app" as `Me` and `Anyone, even anonymous`, respectively. The sample script for Web Apps is as follows.

```
function doGet(e) {return ContentService.createTextOutput("GET: Done.")}
```

### Experiment:

#### Using Google Apps Script:

At first, I checked the status code using Google Apps Script, when it requests to Web Apps. The script is as follows.

```
function myFunction() {
  var url_exec = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";
  var url_dev = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev";
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll([{url: url_exec}, {url: url_dev}]);
  res.forEach(function(e) {
    Logger.log(e.getResponseCode());
  });
}
```

In this case, the status code of `200` was obtained for both endpoints of `exec` and `dev`. Using Google Apps Script, the status code of `403` couldn't be retrieved.

#### Using Curl:

In order to retrieve the status code with curl, `curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://www.example.org/` is used. This is from [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code). Here, the status code was investigated using the curl command. Because the curl can access by 2 kinds of request by the options as showing below.

1. [`--include`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-i): Include the HTTP response headers in the output. The HTTP response headers can include things like server name, cookies, date of the document, HTTP version and more...
2. [`--head`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-I): (HTTP FTP FILE) Fetch the headers only! HTTP-servers feature the command HEAD which this uses to get nothing but the header of a document. When used on an FTP or FILE file, curl displays the file size and last modification time only.

Using above options, the following 4 patterns were investigated.

1. Request to the endpoint of `exec` using the option `--include`.

   - `curl -sL --include -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"`
   - `200` was returned.
2. Request to the endpoint of `dev` using the option `--include`.

   - `curl -sL --include -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev"`
   - `200` was returned.
3. Request to the endpoint of `exec` using the option `--head`.

   - `curl -sL --head -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"`
   - **`403` was returned.**
4. Request to the endpoint of `dev` using the option `--head`.

   - `curl -sL --head -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev"`
   - `200` was returned.

As the result, it was found that when the Web Apps of the endpoint of `exec` was requested with the option `--head`, the status code of `403` was obtained.

### Result and discussions:

When the option `--head` is used for the curl command, from the document, this means that it requests only header and doesn't request the body. By this, it was found that the status code of `403` was returned.

Here, why was the status code of `200` returned for both options of `--include` and `--head` when it requests to the endpoint of `dev`? It is considered that the reason of this is due to that the login screen was returned. When the endpoint of `dev` is accessed, it is required to use the access token. When the access token is not used, the login screen is returned. In this case, the status code of `200` is returned. As the test case, when the access token is used for the endpoint of `dev` using below curl command,

```
curl -sL --head -H "Authorization: Bearer ###" -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev"
```

The status code of `403` was returned. From this result, the following results were obtained.

- When only the header is retrieved under that the Web Apps works fine, `403` is returned.
- When the login screen is returned, `200` is returned.

As the result, it is considered that the reason of error of `{"message":"URL (https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxo90ucgXXz7MG6Z3wb2KD-PJn3akGKoelXLJ2mkg/exec) did not return 200 status code, got 403","error":"ERROR"}` is due to above situation.

### Workaround:

From above results, when the Web Apps is deployed with "Execute the app as" and "Who has access to the app" as `Me` and `Only myself`, respectively, when it requests to the endpoint of `exec` using the option `--head`, it is found that the status code of `200` will be returned. Because at this time, the login screen is displayed.

Using this situation, how about the following flow as a workaround?

1. When the endpoint of Web Apps is registered to the API, please deploy the Web Apps with "Execute the app as" and "Who has access to the app" as `Me` and `Only myself`, respectively.
2. After the registration was completed, please deploy Web Apps with "Execute the app as" and "Who has access to the app" as `Me` and `Anyone, even anonymous`, respectively.

   - By this, the Web Apps can be accessed.

By above flow, only when the endpoint is registered, the status code of `200` is returned. But in this workaround, it supposes that the API you want to use might check the requested header. If my guess was not correct, this workaround cannot be used. In that case, I have to apologize.

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [curl.haxx.se](https://curl.haxx.se/)

### Added:

In my environment, I could confirm that the endpoint of `exec` of Web Apps could be registered with the trello API using above workaround. The script I used is as follows.

- Before you run the script, please set the Web Apps as follows.

  - "Execute the app as" and "Who has access to the app" are `Me` and `Only myself`, respectively.
- After the response of like `{"id":"###","description":"sample","idModel":"###","callbackURL":"https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec","active":true}` was retrieved, please set the Web Apps as follows.

  - "Execute the app as" and "Who has access to the app" are `Me` and `Anyone, even anonymous`, respectively.

By this flow, the webhook can be used.

#### Sample script:

```
var url = 'https://api.trello.com/1/tokens/###/webhooks/?key=###'
var payload = { 
  "callbackURL": "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec",
  "idModel":"###",
  "description": "sample"
}
var options = {method: "post", payload: payload};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
Logger.log(res.getContentText())
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had this same issue and this solution worked for me.  (And saved me hours of frustration, I'm sure!)

Comment: @Aaron Dunigan AtLee Thank you for your comment. I'm glad that my answer was useful for your situation. Thank you, too.